# Soldering iron vs hot air gun

Tags: soldering

I have always used soldering irons of various types. My current one is Hakko FX-888D. I would like to buy a higher-power tool for more bulky work (like soldering banana plugs). So looking for something inexpensive in the vicinity of 200...300 W (based purely on the fact that my Hakko is 70 W).

I see that I have two options: a high-power soldering iron (e.g. Weller SI 251 or TOOLCRAFT KP300) and a hot air gun (is it the correct name? e.g. TOOLCRAFT ZD-8907 or TOOLCRAFT ZD-8908). It makes me wonder, what the application difference is. I understand that the hot air tool is better for desoldering multi-pin devices. But for soldering bulky pieces (wires, plugs), is it considered better or worse than a soldering iron? What are pros/cons?

Comment: There's an entire community of people that review soldering irons and hot air devices on YouTube. You actually have an enormous number of options. I'd suggest looking at recommendations elsewhere before picking a product.

Comment: It is better to call these "desoldering iron/station", not to mix up with regular hot air guns that you use for shrinking tube and the like. You should _not_ use a regular hot air gun obviously, since you need to control the temperature.

Comment: For _soldering_ larger things then using a thicker chisel tip is usually the way to go. Or a beefier soldering iron. On most Hakko you can up the temperature past 400°C when doing job like that. The tips won't last as long with that kind of heat though. Instead of the desoldering iron maybe just invest in a premium soldering iron.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hotair is wonderfully easy if you want to solder many small SMDs at once. Much much easier than with an iron. It is an absolute night and day kind of difference.

But (de)soldering large THT parts is almost impossible with hotair because the part sinks the heat away tonthe rear side.

Likewise it is tricky the solder parts with low melting plastic pieces with hotair. The air is usually much hotter than you would set an iron (>400°C), so it will heat exposed plastic bits to probably more than 300°C, which is much harsher than using an iron on the pin or sticking the whole board in a reflow oven.